# Concatenate tuples in elixir

Tags: elixir

In elixir, we can concatenate, lists like so

```
 ex(52)> [1,2,3,4] ++ [5,6,7]
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Can we also concatenate tuples? Something like this?

```
iex(53)> {1,2,3,4} ++ {5,6,7}
 ** (ArgumentError) argument error
    :erlang.++({1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7})
```

The only other thing I can think of is to convert a tuple to list, then convert back to tuple using the `to_list` and `to_tuple` functions.  But that's way too clumsy.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can't concatenate tuples.

The only reason is that you are not supposed to use them as such. Most of tuple usage requires knowing their size and things get blurrier if you can concatenate them. Furthermore, concatenating tuples requires copying both tuples in memory, which is not efficient.

In other words, if you want to concatenate tuples, you may have the wrong data structure. You have two options:

1. Use lists
2. Compose the tuples: instead of `a ++ b`, just write `{a, b}`

Comment: If I have a situation where I have 2 tuples, and I want to join them together, how should I go about doing it? Would I have to convert the tuples to a list, and then concatenate, and then convert it back to a tuple?

Comment: I love when language designers answer questions. Can't get anymore official than that.

Comment: It's dirty, but as a workaround, `Tuple.to_list` and `List.to_tuple` can be used, taking advantage of list concatenation. I just posted this as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

[@José Valim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28355536/7051394) is (of course) perfectly right, saying that you cannot concatenate tuples with a *language construct*.
Tuples are just not supposed to have their size vary.

However, there **is** a way to *produce a tuple composed of the values of two tuples*.
It's not what you'd call "straightforward", because it goes through a list conversion...
But in some situations, especially when working with legacy code where the original decisions were not the best, it can come in a handy.

So the solution is just to use `Tuple.to_list` and `List.to_tuple`, like this demonstration function:

```
def concat_tuples(t1, t2) do
    List.to_tuple(
        Tuple.to_list(t1) ++ Tuple.to_list(t2)
    )
end
```

Example of use:

```
iex> concat_tuples({1, 2}, {3, 4})
{1, 2, 3, 4}
```

Keep in mind that this is just a workaround, to fix an already broken situation.